# How can I have github do PR merges with a specific email/user info?

Tags: git, github

I have the following situation. At github I have two email address: stefano@home and stefano@work. My github account is configured for stefano@home to be the primary address. At work, I correctly set up my git checkouts to create commits with stefano@work. However, when I go to github and merge PRs onto work's repos, my merge commits appear with stefano@home address.

How can I say that all PR merges on that specific repo must have stefano@work?

Answer (score 9):

Merging from the GitHub UI always *used* the primary email address on your account, ...
But, since April 24th 2019 (4 years later):

"[Choose your merge commit email](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-04-24-choose-your-merge-commit-email/)"

> **You can now choose the author email for commits created when merging pull requests via the web**.
> As a reminder, you can also [choose the author email for web-based edits](https://github.blog/changelog/2018-05-03-choose-commit-email/).

> For more information, see [merging a pull request](https://help.github.com/en/articles/merging-a-pull-request).

[image]

2022: the GUI is also:

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/cb-14417/images/help/pull_requests/merge_box/pullrequest-commitmessage.png]

Reminder:

> If you have more than one email address associated with your account on GitHub.com, click the email address drop-down menu and select the email address to use as the Git author email address.
>
> **Only verified email addresses appear in this drop-down menu**.
> If you enabled email address privacy, then `<username>@users.noreply.github.com` is the default commit author email address.
>
> For more information, see "[Setting your commit email address](https://docs.github.com/en/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address)".

Comment: I don't seem to see that now, did they revert? Or the preference got saved?

Comment: @David Maybe you don't have multiple *verified* email addresses associated with your GitHub account. I have edited the answer with the relevant documentation.

Comment: I reckon it would be helpful if one can configure which email to use by default (when there are more than one verified email for the Github account) for all repositories of an organization.

Comment: @wiser True. I don't think this is supported at the moment (Q4 2022)

Answer (score 7):

Merging from the GitHub UI always uses the [primary email address](https://github.com/settings/emails) on your account, or the private `@users.noreply.github.com` version if you've checked that box. If you want to use different emails per repository, you'll have to `git merge` from the command line. GitHub will still close the PR properly.